# Passing a double to Graphics fillRect method

Tags: java, awt

I am using Java AWT.

I need to use a `double` inside `g.fillrect()` but this function only takes an `int`. Problem is that I need to have `double`. If I have an `int` than java division turns it into zero. How can I work around this?

```
g.fillRect(e.getX(), e.getY(), (double)(e.getWidth() * (e.getHealth() / e.getMaxHealth())), 5);
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific why you need to pass a double value in?

Comment: I doubt that you need to use double parameters for this method. For one thing the screen resolution would not likely be able to differentiate between that fine a degree of difference. Your question smells of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110311/how-to-set-up-health-bar-rect-that-depends-on-health

Comment: That is interesting, but doesn't explain why you need sub-pixel accuracy.

Comment: Amen @VGR. Please improve the question, tell the details of the overall problem. Edit: on looking at that link, I can say without a doubt that you do not need double parameters. Your state fields can be floating point numbers, that will solve the problem of them holding fractional information, but the Graphics fillRect method parameters need to remain ints. Use a scale factor to solve this. Show more pertinent code, and we can likely give you more specific help and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse the size of the visualized health bar with that of the health field. Let's assume that health is an int that goes from 0 to 4. The size of the visualized bar should be:

```
// MAX_HEALTH is a constant, value 4
// maxWidthHealthBar is an int that is the maximal size of the displayed
// healthBar
// healthBarWidth is the length of the colored portion of the health bar
int healthBarWidth = (health * maxWidthHealthBar) / MAX_HEALTH;
```

Do the multiplication first before the division, and your int division should work fine.

Comment: OMG! my bad I was getting the confuse with this size. Thanks, your solution works!

Answer (score 0):

`(int)(e.getWidth() * (double)(e.getHealth() / e.getMaxHealth()))`
This way the result of getHealth()/getMaxHealth() will be a double, which will make the whole result be bigger than zero if and only if `getWidth()*(the-result-fraction)` is bigger than 1.

You could also use `ceil()` if that would get the desired result:
`Math.ceil(e.getWidth() * (double)(e.getHealth() / e.getMaxHealth()));`

Comment: I tried math.ceil but didn't worked. lets say you have (50 * (4/5)) = 0.8 but java turn this into 0. I think I need to print 0.8 inorder to get it to work. what you think?

Comment: @user1924249 If the problem is that the result of the division is smaller than 1, then you need to think about your algorithm. If the method takes ints it means it cannot produce anything sensible for values between 0..1, or anything else fractional, so your problem is not in getting an int, it is in the fact that you do not seem to understand what exactly you are doing.